# How can I have a navigation menu with two rows, one fixed and one collapsable?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm trying to set a navigation menu at the top of the screen with two rows:

- The former one will contain the Brand, and when the resolution is small enough it will also contain the special bootstrap button menu that displays the collapsed menu items stacked.
- The second will contain the categories and will be visible only if the resolution is large enough.

This is what I want to achieve:

[image]
When the resolution is big enough

[image]
When the resolution is small, the second menu row is collapsed

I have used this code without success (The second row never appears):

```
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
            <div class="container">
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".nav-collapse">
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>

            </div>
            <div class="container">
                <div class="nav-collapse collapse">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                        <li><a href="#">Cat1</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Cat2</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Cat3</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="container">
            <p>some text</p>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

I have updated your html code..and after changing a little bit of bootstrap styles you may get what you want..

```
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-static-top" role="navigation">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Project name</a>
        </div>
        <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li><a href="#">Cat1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Cat2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Cat3</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Now set

```
    .navbar-header {
    float: none;
  }
```

Now you will get all links below brand name

In bootstrap we can use media queries to set when to display toggle button in navigation menu.Here we can see toggle button when browser size is 500 px or lesser than 500 px(by default toggle button appears when browser size is lesser than 767 px)..

```
    @media (min-width: 500px) {
        .navbar-collapse {
            width: auto;
            border-top: 0;
            box-shadow: none;
        }

            .navbar-collapse.collapse {
                display: block !important;
                height: auto !important;
                padding-bottom: 0;
                overflow: visible !important;
            }

            .navbar-collapse.in {
                overflow-y: visible;
            }

        .navbar-fixed-top .navbar-collapse,
        .navbar-static-top .navbar-collapse,
        .navbar-fixed-bottom .navbar-collapse {
            padding-right: 0;
            padding-left: 0;
        }

        navbar-collapse.collapse {
            display: block!important;
        }

        .navbar-toggle {
            display: none;
        }

        .navbar-nav > li {
            float: left;
        }
    }

    @media (max-width: 500px) {

        .navbar-toggle {
            display: block;
        }

        .navbar-header {
            float: none;
        }

        .navbar-toggle {
            display: block!important;
        }

        .navbar-collapse {
            border-top: 1px solid transparent;
            box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,0.1);
        }

            .navbar-collapse.collapse {
                display: none!important;
            }

        .navbar-nav {
            float: none!important;
            margin: 7.5px -15px;
        }

            .navbar-nav > li {
                float: none;
            }

                .navbar-nav > li > a {
                    padding-top: 10px;
                    padding-bottom: 10px;
                }
    }
```

Hope this helps you!!!!!